# Not able to describe EBS snapshots more than 1000

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Trying to list all the snapshots present in a region using boto3, but not able to list more than 1000. Is there a workaround for this to list all the ebs snapshots?

```
def ebssnapsot(aws_id):
    response = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(
        MaxResults=100000,
        )
    print(json.dumps(response, indent=2, default=str))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to paginate through multiple requests to get all the values. You can either do this yourself via the `NextToken` parameter in the `describe_snapshots()` call, or you can use the built-in [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Paginator.DescribeSnapshots).

Comment: How can we loop then using NextToken?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323546/how-to-use-nexttoken-in-boto3

Comment: thanks!
Tried that workaround & it helped. 


but the snapshots are above 200,000 and it's unable to fetch them resulting in erroring out with timeout from reading aws service

Comment: will be trying with increasing timeout - 

```ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', config=Config(read_timeout=400))```

Comment: Even using the below config its erroring out with - 

 `raise ReadTimeoutError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/"`

config: 

`ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='ap-south-1',config=Config(read_timeout=1000,connect_timeout=1000,retries={'max_attempts': 0}))`

Comment: So some of the calls are working, but some of them time out? Or are they all timing out?

Comment: all are timing out

Comment: Are you running this in an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: No actually on Argo Workflow, as a script